# Pass variable from XLSM to embedded DOCM

Tags: vba, excel, ms-word

I have an embedded Word document `(*.docm)` in my Excel worksheet.

The Word document contains a `table`, that has relationship between its corresponding `Table` in Excel's `WorkSheet`.

**I want count of table rows in embedded Word document been dynamically set in `Document_Open` event, with bellow value, from its involving Worksheet:**

```
ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet1").ListObjects("Salary").ListRows.Count
```

How can I pass values between Excel (macro container document) and its embedded macro container word document? -If its a right answer for above bold issue- or another solution?

If there is another solution answer, Please note that cover need of:

Fill destination table (that is in embedded word document) cells with corresponding values from source data are in parent Table from Worksheet?, same instead of with auto generating fields with Document_Open events from macro container embedded word document.

Answer (score 1):

I suggest to embed .docx document to avoid macros disabled alert each time it's opened, and to place all the code within Excel VBA Project. Here is the example, showing how to change number of rows in embedded Word document from Excel VBA:

```vb
Sub ChangeRowsCount()

    Dim n As Long

    With ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet1")
        n = .ListObjects("Table1").ListRows.Count
        With .Shapes("Object 1")
            Select Case True
                Case .Type <> msoEmbeddedOLEObject
                    MsgBox "Invalid OLE Object type"
                Case InStr(1, .OLEFormat.progID, "Word.Document", vbTextCompare) <> 1
                    MsgBox "Invalid Application"
                Case Else
                    .OLEFormat.Object.Verb xlVerbOpen
                    With .OLEFormat.Object.Object.Parent ' Word.Application
                        With .ActiveDocument.Tables(1).Rows
                            Do While .Count <> n
                                If .Count > n Then .Item(.Count).Delete Else .Add
                            Loop
                        End With
                        .Quit
                    End With
                    .Select
                    MsgBox "Success"
            End Select
        End With
    End With

End Sub
```

Comment: With thanks;  thus I extend question: And then, How can we fill destination table (that is in embedded word document) cells with corresponding values from source data are in parent `Table` from `Worksheet`?, **against with auto generating fields with `Document_Open` events from embedded word document.**

Comment: @MGae2M In the answer I suggested **not to use VBA and events from embeded document**, but do it from Excel VBA.

Comment: So, how can we fill destination table (that is in embedded word document) cells with corresponding values from source data are in source `Table` is in `Worksheet`? Seems need running some Word methods as `Selection.TypeText Text:= ...` from Excel module or better act for filling the table in embedded word document. How can we use Word methods in Excel module, pass variable, or better way for do that? As I extended my above question, please extend your answer involving this matter.